# Yii2:: cant acess to module from url

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

im used CRUD for generate module template. Activate module on config file web.php.

```
'admin' => [
            'class' => 'app\modules\admin\AdminModule',
        ],
```

and after can't to access:
`http://blog/web/index.php?r=admin`

Comment: have you placed this in `components` for eg `components=>['admin'=>['class'=>'app\modules\admin\AdminModule']]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm solved this. I added module activation code on modules $config froperty web.php file.

```
$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [
        'admin' => [
            'class' => 'app\modules\admin\admin',
        ],
    ],
```